# Gnome New Windows not focused automatically

Tags: window, focus, 22.10

This started happening for me in Ubuntu 22.10 Whenever I open a new window with a shortcut, for example I use the right ALT to open the terminal, the focus does not go to that newly opened windows, but stays in whichever app I am still in.

How can I make it so it behaves like 22.04 where the focus will always go to the newly opened windows.

This only happens to opened apps with shortcuts as it looks, but not with clicked apps or apps opened from the dock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Talk about answering ones question too fast. So anyway, the one I was previously testing was:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'strict'`

But it never worked. Then I tried just for kicks:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'smart'`

and it worked. Hope this helps anyone with this weird error.

Comment: works. when i reboot seems i need to do it again. do i need a autostart - sh script then with this line in?